# Human readable date format when converting json to xml

Tags: c#, mongodb, xml-serialization, json.net, mongodb-.net-driver

After fetching data from MongoDB, i convert it to json and then serialize it to XML data using the Json serializer for .net. All the fields and their values are correclty converted and displayed in XML except the Date field which is displayed as shown below in the XML Document. Is there any way to make this  date field human readable?

```
<dob json:date="1413191676440" xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json" />
```

Comment: The quickest way is to deserialize it into a strongly typed class then serialize that to xml

Comment: To help you understand: This is the internal date representation of MongoDB, the milliseconds since 00:00 on January 1st, 1970. See [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for details.